# JS return escaped regex to original format

Tags: javascript

I have a function that accepts a regex as a string, and a value, then tries to evaluate if the value matches the regex. The function is called in a json schema, hence i have to escape the regex to avoid errors. I am having a hard time removing the escape quotes in my function so that i can validate that i the value meets the regex criteria :
This is how my json schema looks :

```
{
  "type": "patientIdentifier",
  "label": "Recency Id",
  "questionInfo": "",
  "id": "recencyId",
  "required": "false",
  "default": "",
  "questionOptions": {
    "rendering": "text",
    "identifierType": "fd52829a-75d2-4732-8e43-4bff8e5b4f1a"
  },
  "validators": [{
    "type": "js_expression",
    "failsWhenExpression": "doesNotMatchExpression(\"/^REC\\d{5}-\\d{5,6}$/\", recencyId)",
    "message": "Please provide the correct format for the recency id ie. REC+mflCode+number eg.REC11902-00062"
  }]
}
```

This is how my function looks :

```
function doesNotMatchExpression(regexString, val) {
  console.log("val", val);
  console.log("regexstring", regexString);
  if (!val || ['undefined', 'null', ''].includes(val.toString())) {
    return true;
  }
  const cleanedRegexString = eval(regexString);
  const regex = new RegExp(cleanedRegexString);
  console.log("---h", regex.test(val));
  console.log("---p", regex);
  if (!regex.test(val)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

I have tried using `eval` and `regexString.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')` but the regex is not back to the original value, the backslashes are still removed.

Any advise/links to read will be appreciated.

Comment: can you show how yo call `doesNotMatchExpression` - my guess is, your error is there

Comment: What is the actual, original expression you tried to put into your JSON there? Right now, you have encoded the value `doesNotMatchExpression("/^REC\\d{5}-\\d{5,6}$/", recencyId)`, but I kinda doubt that makes sense to begin with, with the double backslashes in front of the `d` there ...?

Comment: @CBroe My original expression is `/^REC\d{5}-\d{5,6}$/`

Comment: Just doing evil `eval("doesNotMatchExpression(\"/^REC\\d{5}-\\d{5,6}$/\", 'REC11902-00062')")` for a quick try , it evaluates and validates perfectly fine. It would be nice to know at which point of the eval/validation process the OP does encounter the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An idea may be a setup where you split the function name from the regular expression. The function name can be a key of an Object containing the actual value to test. A [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```js
const singleOut = {
  validators: [{
    "type": "js_expression",
    "function": "doesNotMatchExpression",
    "regularExpression": "^REC\\d{5}-\\d{5,6}$",
    "regexModifiers": "",
    "message": "Please provide the correct format for the recency id ie. REC+mflCode+number eg.REC11902-00062",
    "okMessage": "Checks out ok"
    }]
};

const validators = validatorsFactory();
const validator = singleOut.validators[0];
console.log(`The RegExp: ${RegExp(validator.regularExpression, validator.regexModifiers)}`);

const validate = value => 
  validators[validator.function](
    value, 
    validator.regularExpression, 
    validator.regexModifiers,
    validator.message,
    validator.okMessage );

console.log(validate(`rec23-2345`));
console.log(validate(`rec62423-000780`));
console.log(validate(`REC62423-000780`));

function validatorsFactory() {
  return {
    doesNotMatchExpression: (value, regex, modifiers, message, ok) => 
      RegExp(regex, modifiers).test(value) && `${value} => ${ok}`|| 
        `${value} => ${message}`,
  };
}
```